# performSegueWithIdentifier destinationViewController deallocs with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Odd issue here:

I created a storyboard with two view controllers, connected with a custom segue(a cross disolve).  I make the segue happen by:

```
-(void)transitionToIntro
{ 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToIntro" sender:self];
}
```

This transitions and I see the new view controller, After the initWithCoder and AwakeFromNib it sets up the UI and I see that the properties for data source and delegates are set.  THen all of a sudden dealloc is fired!  and this destination view controller is dealloc'd.  Then of course everything is bunked.  Delegates are nil and Datasources are nil because the containing viewcontroller is invalid to the subviews that contained it...

I dont know why this is happening, is the source viewcontroller not retaining a strong hold on the destination viewcontroller?

I have made sure to make the initial view controller set in the story board to my source view controller.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In prepareForSegue method are you storing the segue's destinationViewcontroller? Posting that code will be helpful.

Comment: I was not...Im not doing a prepareForSegue... perhaps thats my issue !  Ah that was it, I needed to make a property for the source VC to hold on to the dest VC and set that in my prepareForSegue... Im a bit new to storyboarding.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Make sure to have your source VC have a retained strong reference to the destination VC , and set that in prepareForSegue.  If not you will see your destination VC dealloc itself after running initWithCoder and AwakeFromNib.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IntroViewController *destVC; 




 -(void)transitionToIntro
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToIntro" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToIntro"])
    {
        IntroViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
       self.destVC = dest;
    }
}
```